# How to store results returned from SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm a rookie, as evinced by my question, and I'm using a datareader to find the rows associated with a certain subId value. I used a while(dr.read) loop and nested a switch case statement with other readers in each case (code below), but I threw the exception "already an open data reader associated with this command which must be closed first." Is there a way to store the results of the first datareader (the relevant rows where subId = x) in an array, or list, and then close that reader before I enter my switch statement? (I understand what an array is to the extent that I imagine it would work, but I haven't a clue what the syntax would look like).

```
string viewQuery = "SELECT ProductId FROM SubmissionProducts WHERE SubmissionId =" + x;



            using (SqlCommand viewcmd = new SqlCommand(viewQuery, editConn))
            {
                SqlDataReader dr = viewcmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    switch(dr.GetInt32(0))
                    {
                        case 1:
                            PanelEplShow.Visible = true;
                            using (SqlCommand eplviewcmd = new SqlCommand(epl, editConn))
                            {
                                SqlDataReader epldr = eplviewcmd.ExecuteReader();
                                epldr.Read();
                                LblEplShowEntity.Text = epldr.GetString(0);
                                LblEplShowTotalEmpl.Text = epldr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                                LblEplShowCalEmpl.Text = epldr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                                LblEplShowMichEmpl.Text = epldr.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                                LblEplShowNyEmpl.Text = epldr.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                                LblEplShowNjEmpl.Text = epldr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                                LblEplShowPrimEx.Text = epldr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                                LblEplShowLim.Text = epldr.GetInt32(7).ToString();
                                LblEplShowPrem.Text = epldr.GetInt32(8).ToString();
                                LblEplShowWage.Text = epldr.GetInt32(9).ToString();
                                LblEplShowInvestCost.Text = epldr.GetInt32(10).ToString();
                                epldr.Close();
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            PanelProfShow.Visible = true;
                            using (SqlCommand profcmd1 = new SqlCommand(prof, editConn))
                            {
                                SqlDataReader profdr = profcmd1.ExecuteReader();
                                profdr.Read();
                                LblProfShowPrimEx.Text = profdr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                                LblProfShowType.Text = profdr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                                LblProfShowLim.Text = profdr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                                LblProfShowRetention.Text = profdr.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                                LblProfShowAtt.Text = profdr.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                                LblProfShowPrem.Text = profdr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                                LblProfShowSublim.Text = profdr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                                LblProfShowEntity.Text = profdr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                                profdr.Close();
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            PanelCrimeShow.Visible = true;
                            using (SqlCommand crimcmd = new SqlCommand(crim, editConn))
                            {
                                SqlDataReader crimdr = crimcmd.ExecuteReader();
                                crimdr.Read();
                                LblCrimeShowEntity.Text = crimdr.GetString(0);
                                LblCrimeShowEmpl.Text = crimdr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                                LblCrimeShowPrimEx.Text = crimdr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                                LblCrimeShowLimA.Text = crimdr.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                                LblCrimeShowDedA.Text = crimdr.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                                LblCrimeShowPremA.Text = crimdr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                                LblCrimeShowLimB.Text = crimdr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                                LblCrimeShowDedB.Text = crimdr.GetInt32(7).ToString();
                                LblCrimeShowPremB.Text = crimdr.GetInt32(8).ToString();
                                crimdr.Close();
                            }
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            PanelFidShow.Visible = true;
                            using (SqlCommand fidcmd = new SqlCommand(fid, editConn))
                            {
                                SqlDataReader fiddr = fidcmd.ExecuteReader();
                                fiddr.Read();
                                LblFidShowEntity.Text = fiddr.GetString(0);
                                LblFidShowPrimEx.Text = fiddr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                                LblFidShowLim.Text = fiddr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                                LblFidShowSir.Text = fiddr.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                                LblFidShowAtt.Text = fiddr.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                                LblFidShowPrem.Text = fiddr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                                LblFidShowSublim.Text = fiddr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                                fiddr.Close();
                            }
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            PanelNotShow.Visible = true;
                            using (SqlCommand notcmd = new SqlCommand(not, editConn))
                            {
                                SqlDataReader notdr = notcmd.ExecuteReader();
                                notdr.Read();
                                LblNotShowPrimEx.Text = notdr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                                LblNotShowCov.Text = notdr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                                LblNotShowSharedLim.Text = notdr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                                LblNotShowTradLim.Text = notdr.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                                LblNotShowTradSir.Text = notdr.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                                LblNotShowEplLim.Text = notdr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                                LblNotShowEplSir.Text = notdr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                                LblNotShowEplPrem.Text = notdr.GetInt32(7).ToString();
                                LblNotShowSublim.Text = notdr.GetInt32(8).ToString();
                                notdr.Close();
                            }
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            PanelPrivShow.Visible = true;
                            using (SqlCommand privcmd = new SqlCommand(priv, editConn))
                            {
                                SqlDataReader privdr = privcmd.ExecuteReader();
                                privdr.Read();
                                LblPrivShowPrimEx.Text = privdr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                                LblPrivShowSharedLim.Text = privdr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                                LblPrivShowTradLim.Text = privdr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                                LblPrivShowTradAtt.Text = privdr.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                                LblPrivShowTradSir.Text = privdr.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                                LblPrivShowTradPrem.Text = privdr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                                LblPrivShowEplLim.Text = privdr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                                LblPrivShowEplSir.Text = privdr.GetInt32(7).ToString();
                                LblPrivShowEplAtt.Text = privdr.GetInt32(8).ToString();
                                LblPrivShowEplPrem.Text = privdr.GetInt32(9).ToString();
                                LblPrivShowEplWage.Text = privdr.GetInt32(10).ToString();
                                LblPrivShowEplSublim.Text = privdr.GetInt32(11).ToString();
                                LblPrivShowFidLim.Text = privdr.GetInt32(12).ToString();
                                LblPrivShowFidSir.Text = privdr.GetInt32(13).ToString();
                                LblPrivShowFidAtt.Text = privdr.GetInt32(14).ToString();
                                LblPrivShowFidPrem.Text = privdr.GetInt32(15).ToString();
                                LblPrivShowFidSublim.Text = privdr.GetInt32(16).ToString();
                                privdr.Close();
                            }
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            PanelPubShow.Visible = true;
                            using (SqlCommand pubcmd = new SqlCommand(pub, editConn))
                            {
                                SqlDataReader pubdr = pubcmd.ExecuteReader();
                                pubdr.Read();
                                LblPubShowMark.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                                LblPubShowTick.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                                LblPubShowTrad.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                                LblPubShowDic.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                                LblPubShowLim.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                                LblPubShowSecSir.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                                LblPubShowAllSir.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                                LblPubShowPrem.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(7).ToString();
                                LblPubShowPrimEx.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(8).ToString();
                                LblPubShowAtt.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(9).ToString();
                                LblPubShowSublim.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(10).ToString();
                                pubdr.Close();
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                dr.Close();`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found I had to adjust something in my connection string. I don't know if it's a .Net glitch or whether it's just a necessary adjustment when using nested readers, but I had to add `MultipleActiveResultSets="true"` to my stored connection string. Afterwards, everything worked properly, with no need for a datatable. Many thanks to everyone who answered. While I'm sure the answers above could also have worked, in case this question is of any utility to someone in the future, I'm posting the full code to show what worked for me. *Word of caution: if you're new enough to coding to need this post, PARAMETERIZE your queries. This site was a training project where I was instructed to avoid parameterizing in the interest of learning other things first, but it's paramount. Bobby tables ftw.*

Here's the code.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class View : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string x = Request.QueryString["SubmissionId"];
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string editCustQuery = "SELECT CustName, SicNaic, CustCity, CustAdd, CustState, CustZip FROM Customer WHERE SubId =" + x;
        string editBroQuery = "SELECT BroName, BroAdd, BroCity, BroState, BroZip, EntityType FROM Broker WHERE SubId =" + x; 
        string editSubQuery = "SELECT Coverage, CurrentCoverage, PrimEx, Retention, EffectiveDate, Commission, Premium, Comments FROM Submission WHERE SubmissionId =" + x;
        string epl = "SELECT Entity, Employees, CA, MI, NY, NJ, Primex, EplLim, EplSir, Premium, Wage, Sublim FROM EPL WHERE SubmissionId =" + x;
        string prof = "SELECT Primex, EO, Limit, Retention, Att, Prem, Sublim, Entity FROM ProfessionalEO WHERE SubmissionId =" + x;
        string crim = "SELECT Entity, Employees, PrimEx, LimA, DedA, PremA, LimitB, DedB, PremB FROM CrimeFidelity WHERE SubmissionId =" + x;
        string fid = "SELECT Entity, PrimEx, Limit, SIR, Att, Premium, Sublim FROM Fiduciary WHERE SubmissionId =" + x;
        string not = "SELECT PrimEx, Coverage, SharedSepLim, TradLim, TradDoSir, EplLim, EplSir, EplPrem, EplSublim FROM NotProfit WHERE SubmissionId =" + x;
        string priv = "SELECT Primex, SharedSepLim, TradLim, TradAtt, TradDoSir, TradPrem, EplLim, EplSir, EplAtt, EplWage, EplPrem, EplInvest, FidLim, FidSir, FidAtt, FidPrem, FidSublim FROM PrivateCompany WHERE SubmissionId =" + x;
        string pub = "SELECT Market, Ticker, TradABC, DIC, Limit, SecuritiesSir, OtherSir, Premium, PrimEx, Att, Sublim FROM PublicDO WHERE SubmissionId =" + x;
        using (SqlConnection editConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            editConn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand CustCommand = new SqlCommand(editCustQuery, editConn))
            {

                SqlDataReader dr = CustCommand.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();
                LblCustName.Text = dr.GetString(0);
                LblSicNaic.Text = dr.GetString(1);
                LblCustCity.Text = dr.GetString(2);
                LblCustAddress.Text = dr.GetString(3);
                LblCustState.Text = dr.GetString(4);
                LblCustZip.Text = dr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                dr.Close();
            }
            using (SqlCommand BroCommand = new SqlCommand(editBroQuery, editConn))
            {
                SqlDataReader dr = BroCommand.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();
                LblBroName.Text = dr.GetString(0);
                LblBroAddress.Text = dr.GetString(1);
                LblBroCity.Text = dr.GetString(2);
                LblBroState.Text = dr.GetString(3);
                LblBroZip.Text = dr.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                LblEntity.Text = dr.GetString(5);
                dr.Close();
            }
            using (SqlCommand SubCommand = new SqlCommand(editSubQuery, editConn))
            {
                SqlDataReader dr = SubCommand.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();
                LblCoverage.Text = dr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                LblCurrentCoverage.Text = dr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                LblPrimEx.Text = dr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                LblRetention.Text = dr.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                LblEffectDate.Text = dr.GetDateTime(4).ToString();
                LblCommission.Text = dr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                LblPremium.Text = dr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                LblComments.Text = dr.GetString(7);
                dr.Close();
                HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "~/ViewEdit.aspx?SubmissionId=" + x;
            }
                string viewQuery = "SELECT ProductId FROM SubmissionProducts WHERE SubmissionId =" + x;

                SqlCommand viewcmd = new SqlCommand(viewQuery, editConn);

                SqlDataReader drRows = viewcmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (drRows.Read())
                    {
                        switch (drRows.GetInt32(0))
                        {
                            case 1:
                                PanelEplShow.Visible = true;
                                using (SqlCommand eplviewcmd = new SqlCommand(epl, editConn))
                                {
                                    SqlDataReader epldr = eplviewcmd.ExecuteReader();
                                    epldr.Read();
                                    LblEplShowEntity.Text = epldr.GetString(0);
                                    LblEplShowTotalEmpl.Text = epldr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                                    LblEplShowCalEmpl.Text = epldr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                                    LblEplShowMichEmpl.Text = epldr.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                                    LblEplShowNyEmpl.Text = epldr.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                                    LblEplShowNjEmpl.Text = epldr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                                    LblEplShowPrimEx.Text = epldr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                                    LblEplShowLim.Text = epldr.GetInt32(7).ToString();
                                    LblEplShowSir.Text = epldr.GetInt32(8).ToString();
                                    LblEplShowPrem.Text = epldr.GetInt32(9).ToString();
                                    LblEplShowWage.Text = epldr.GetInt32(10).ToString();
                                    LblEplShowInvestCost.Text = epldr.GetInt32(11).ToString();
                                    epldr.Close();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                PanelProfShow.Visible = true;
                                using (SqlCommand profcmd = new SqlCommand(prof, editConn))
                                {
                                    SqlDataReader profdr = profcmd.ExecuteReader();
                                    profdr.Read();
                                    LblProfShowPrimEx.Text = profdr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                                    LblProfShowType.Text = profdr.GetString(1);
                                    LblProfShowLim.Text = profdr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                                    LblProfShowRetention.Text = profdr.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                                    LblProfShowAtt.Text = profdr.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                                    LblProfShowPrem.Text = profdr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                                    LblProfShowSublim.Text = profdr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                                    LblProfShowEntity.Text = profdr.GetString(7);
                                    profdr.Close();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                PanelCrimeShow.Visible = true;
                                using (SqlCommand crimcmd = new SqlCommand(crim, editConn))
                                {
                                    SqlDataReader crimdr = crimcmd.ExecuteReader();
                                    crimdr.Read();
                                    LblCrimeShowEntity.Text = crimdr.GetString(0);
                                    LblCrimeShowEmpl.Text = crimdr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                                    LblCrimeShowPrimEx.Text = crimdr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                                    LblCrimeShowLimA.Text = crimdr.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                                    LblCrimeShowDedA.Text = crimdr.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                                    LblCrimeShowPremA.Text = crimdr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                                    LblCrimeShowLimB.Text = crimdr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                                    LblCrimeShowDedB.Text = crimdr.GetInt32(7).ToString();
                                    LblCrimeShowPremB.Text = crimdr.GetInt32(8).ToString();
                                    crimdr.Close();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                PanelFidShow.Visible = true;
                                using (SqlCommand fidcmd = new SqlCommand(fid, editConn))
                                {
                                    SqlDataReader fiddr = fidcmd.ExecuteReader();
                                    fiddr.Read();
                                    LblFidShowEntity.Text = fiddr.GetString(0);
                                    LblFidShowPrimEx.Text = fiddr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                                    LblFidShowLim.Text = fiddr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                                    LblFidShowSir.Text = fiddr.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                                    LblFidShowAtt.Text = fiddr.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                                    LblFidShowPrem.Text = fiddr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                                    LblFidShowSublim.Text = fiddr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                                    fiddr.Close();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                PanelNotShow.Visible = true;
                                using (SqlCommand notcmd = new SqlCommand(not, editConn))
                                {
                                    SqlDataReader notdr = notcmd.ExecuteReader();
                                    notdr.Read();
                                    LblNotShowPrimEx.Text = notdr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                                    LblNotShowCov.Text = notdr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                                    LblNotShowSharedLim.Text = notdr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                                    LblNotShowTradLim.Text = notdr.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                                    LblNotShowTradSir.Text = notdr.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                                    LblNotShowEplLim.Text = notdr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                                    LblNotShowEplSir.Text = notdr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                                    LblNotShowEplPrem.Text = notdr.GetInt32(7).ToString();
                                    LblNotShowSublim.Text = notdr.GetInt32(8).ToString();
                                    notdr.Close();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                PanelPrivShow.Visible = true;
                                using (SqlCommand privcmd = new SqlCommand(priv, editConn))
                                {
                                    SqlDataReader privdr = privcmd.ExecuteReader();
                                    privdr.Read();
                                    LblPrivShowPrimEx.Text = privdr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                                    LblPrivShowSharedLim.Text = privdr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                                    LblPrivShowTradLim.Text = privdr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                                    LblPrivShowTradAtt.Text = privdr.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                                    LblPrivShowTradSir.Text = privdr.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                                    LblPrivShowTradPrem.Text = privdr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                                    LblPrivShowEplLim.Text = privdr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                                    LblPrivShowEplSir.Text = privdr.GetInt32(7).ToString();
                                    LblPrivShowEplAtt.Text = privdr.GetInt32(8).ToString();
                                    LblPrivShowEplPrem.Text = privdr.GetInt32(9).ToString();
                                    LblPrivShowEplWage.Text = privdr.GetInt32(10).ToString();
                                    LblPrivShowEplSublim.Text = privdr.GetInt32(11).ToString();
                                    LblPrivShowFidLim.Text = privdr.GetInt32(12).ToString();
                                    LblPrivShowFidSir.Text = privdr.GetInt32(13).ToString();
                                    LblPrivShowFidAtt.Text = privdr.GetInt32(14).ToString();
                                    LblPrivShowFidPrem.Text = privdr.GetInt32(15).ToString();
                                    LblPrivShowFidSublim.Text = privdr.GetInt32(16).ToString();
                                    privdr.Close();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 7:
                                PanelPubShow.Visible = true;
                                using (SqlCommand pubcmd = new SqlCommand(pub, editConn))
                                {
                                    SqlDataReader pubdr = pubcmd.ExecuteReader();
                                    pubdr.Read();
                                    LblPubShowMark.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                                    LblPubShowTick.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
                                    LblPubShowTrad.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                                    LblPubShowDic.Text = pubdr.GetString(3);
                                    LblPubShowLim.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                                    LblPubShowSecSir.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                                    LblPubShowAllSir.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                                    LblPubShowPrem.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(7).ToString();
                                    LblPubShowPrimEx.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(8).ToString();
                                    LblPubShowAtt.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(9).ToString();
                                    LblPubShowSublim.Text = pubdr.GetInt32(10).ToString();
                                    pubdr.Close();
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                drRows.Close();

        }        
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Load it into a `DataTable`.

```
SqlDataReader pubdr = pubcmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(pubdr);
```

To expand on the comments:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    LblEplShowEntity.Text = dr["FIELDNAME"].ToString();
    //...
}
```

Comment: dt.Rows[rowindex][columnName/columnIndex]

Answer (score 3):

Load a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) instead, which internally is a persisted DataReader anyway

For a DataReader you consume, use, discard. This is the nature of DataReaders. If you want the data to hang around, you'd use a DataTable. Simple, but a good rule of thumb.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming **SubmissionId** is unique in the table **SubmissionProducts** , you don't need to use a data reader for the query. You can instead use the [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method of the command object.

If you want to get an array of all the collumn values in the current row from a DataReader you can use the [GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalues.aspx) method like this:

```
    SqlDataReader reader; // assumming the data reader is already opened 
    object[] columns = new object[reader.FieldCount];
    reader.GetValues(columns);// columns now contains all the values from the curent row
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no, SubmissionId can have multiple instances associated with it.